# Error while mounting reiser4 filesystem

Tags: filesystems, mount, debian-squeeze, reiserfs

I'm using Debian 6.03 (2.6.32-5-amd64) with LVM configured. For testing I created testfs logical volume and formatted it in reiser4 filesystem. But when I try:

`# mount /dev/lv-group/testfs /mnt`

it says:

`mount: unknown filesystem type 'reiser4'`

`reiser4progs` are also installed. What's the problem?

Comment: What feature are you using the reiser filesystem for over some of the other very stable filesystems out there like ext4? ext3? xfs?

Comment: @mdpc it's just testing of filesystem's performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't running a patched kernel with reiser4 support.  It was never merged into the mainline kernel and since Hans Reiser is in prison for the murder of his Wife, it is a dead filesystem.  If you are looking for similar features, look at btrfs, but it is still not ready for production environments.

Comment: ok, is it good idea to use btrfs in system which reads/writes ~2k or more small files?

Comment: @mickey, yes, btrfs handles small files well.